# Xamarin.Android Custom DialogFragment not fully displaying

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am having a problem displaying my custom dialog fragment.I am now out of ideas,tried setting values for the layout_width and length and it did help.Still a beginner so would really need your help.Here is my custom dialog fragment XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#DEDEDC"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="400dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/txtFirstName"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtEmail" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Sign Up!"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnDialogEmail"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:height="70dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignUpStyle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The Custom DialogFragment.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace TalkPlus1
{
    class MyFragment:DialogFragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View view = LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentLayout, container, attachToRoot: false);

            return view;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        }
    }
```

and my ActivityMain.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TalkPlus1
{
    [Activity(Label = "TalkPlus1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button btnLogin, btnRegister;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            btnLogin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myLogin);
            btnRegister = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.mySignUp);

            btnLogin.Click += BtnLogin_Click;
            btnRegister.Click += BtnRegister_Click;

        }

        private void BtnRegister_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, text: "jwndhawb", duration: ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            FragmentTransaction transact = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            var df = new DialogFragment();
            df.Show(transact, tag: "dialog");
        }

    }


}
```

The dialog fragment displays like

[DialogFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnNDW.jpg)

Comment: You should also provide a screenshot how it looks like, because we don't know what do you mean about "not fully displaying"

Comment: you  are getting empty dialog because    var df = new DialogFragment();         and Fragmenttransaction has noting to show in transact variable;